# Wilcoxon Rank Sum test in every possible combinations

Tags: r

I have 5 populations of values and I want to run Wilcoxon Rank Sum test in every possible combinations.

After running the test I want to store the p-values in a matrix. I am
also attaching the dataset.

```
Population1 Population2 Population3 Population4 Population5
3.09    3.51349697  3.164190018 3.518407469 3.620480389
2.575   3.635713772 3.856745405 3.795780041 3.47405986
4.045   4.345129949 3.723526111 4.033668309 3.799417462
4.05    4.228530049 3.782229842 3.90679146  3.781252404
2.36    3.656315008 3.590211196 3.204999548 3.333981072
3.265   4.190930929 3.712583274 3.927421494 3.597604196
3.86    4.34070563  3.860239538 4.047323965 3.765763075
3.715   3.932171123 3.575872952 3.360518373 3.362403803
3.155   3.743746825 3.87061761  3.722034198 3.716139828
```

I have written a code but it is returning the last column only

```
    x=read.csv("Book1.csv")

    pvalue<-matrix(nrow=5, ncol=5)

    for(i in 1:length(x)){
      for(j in 1:length(x)){
      pvalue[i*j]<-wilcox.test(x[,i], x[,j], paired=TRUE)$p.value 
      colnames(pvalue) <- colnames(x)
      rownames(pvalue)<- colnames(x)
    }
   }
```

I want the output in this format

[image]

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: What about using `kruskal.test()` which implements the Kruskal - Wallis test, which is the extension of Wilcoxon Rank Sum test for more than two groups?

Comment: Your `p.value` computation code is present outside the inner loop hence it runs only once. Also add the line `cat(i,j,"\n")` prior to `p.value` computation to inform user which indices are being processed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there; just two small errors: your first } is too early, and length(x) is the length of the full matrix, that is 45 instead of 5 which is what you want here.

This should work:

```
    for(i in 1:length(colnames(x))){
           for(j in 1:length(colnames(x))){
              pvalue[i,j]<-wilcox.test(x[,i], x[,j], paired=TRUE)$p.value 
     colnames(pvalue) <- colnames(x)
     rownames(pvalue)<- colnames(x)} }
```

Comment: I used the idea of this code for my data but it gives me "There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)"

Comment: As per your comment and question linked to below the reason why the warnings occur is due to your data, not due to the code.

Answer (score 3):

You can use pairwise.wilcox.test which will return you exactly the matrix you want with correction for multiple comparison.

```
library('MASS')
X <- mvrnorm(100,1:5, diag(5))
pairwise.wilcox.test(t(X), g = seq(1,5), p.adjust.method = 'BH')
```

g is a factor that defines the groups so after the transpose your first row is group 1 second row group 2 and so on.

Comment: I used the idea of this code for my data but it gives me "There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)"

Comment: please elaborate

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60112609/warnings-in-wilcoxon-rank-sum-test-in-r?noredirect=1#comment106318218_60112609