# Warnings in Wilcoxon Rank Sum test in R

Tags: r

I want to do the Wilcoxon Rank Sum test with every possible combination in R.

I found this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43654787/wilcoxon-rank-sum-test-in-every-possible-combinations), which has two related answers. However, I used both of them, but it gives me "There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)"

```
In wilcox.test.default(x[, i], x[, j], paired = TRUE) :
  cannot compute exact p-value with ties

In wilcox.test.default(x[, i], x[, j], paired = TRUE) :
  cannot compute exact p-value with zeroes
```

I will provide my data and the code I used, which I take from the mentioned question.

```
x = read.table(text="

                  2.77E-06  6.89E-06    4.81E-05    2.52E-06    1.13E-05    3.19E-06    3.14E-06    4.57E-06    4.50E-06    4.13E-06    3.55E-06    2.77E-06
                  4.20E-06  6.68E-06    7.21E-05    2.71E-06    1.44E-05    3.98E-06    3.94E-06    6.02E-06    5.95E-06    5.54E-06    4.92E-06    4.20E-06
                  4.20E-06  9.63E-06    5.51E-05    2.84E-06    1.47E-05    4.46E-06    4.46E-06    7.64E-06    7.54E-06    6.95E-06    5.96E-06    4.20E-06
                  4.40E-06  8.40E-06    5.15E-05    3.61E-06    1.27E-05    4.32E-06    4.19E-06    7.03E-06    6.93E-06    6.40E-06    5.56E-06    4.40E-06
                  5.04E-06  9.64E-06    3.76E-05    3.27E-06    1.39E-05    5.15E-06    4.96E-06    7.72E-06    7.64E-06    7.18E-06    6.40E-06    5.04E-06
                  4.09E-06  8.37E-06    5.65E-05    2.71E-06    1.31E-05    3.88E-06    3.82E-06    6.12E-06    6.03E-06    5.55E-06    4.82E-06    4.09E-06
                  3.98E-06  9.51E-06    5.24E-05    3.50E-06    1.41E-05    4.49E-06    4.57E-06    4.73E-06    4.70E-06    4.55E-06    4.32E-06    3.98E-06
                  3.01E-06  7.20E-06    5.62E-05    2.43E-06    1.51E-05    3.58E-06    3.70E-06    4.66E-06    4.61E-06    4.35E-06    3.92E-06    3.01E-06
                  2.88E-06  7.07E-06    5.42E-05    2.02E-06    1.07E-05    2.86E-06    2.92E-06    4.94E-06    4.86E-06    4.41E-06    3.73E-06    2.88E-06
                  3.33E-06  5.75E-06    5.64E-05    2.36E-06    1.51E-05    3.45E-06    3.52E-06    5.12E-06    5.06E-06    4.71E-06    4.16E-06    3.33E-06
                  4.20E-06  8.36E-06    4.82E-05    3.14E-06    1.32E-05    3.93E-06    3.73E-06    5.97E-06    5.87E-06    5.38E-06    4.64E-06    4.20E-06
                  4.80E-06  8.00E-06    4.24E-05    2.43E-06    1.79E-05    4.76E-06    4.68E-06    8.87E-06    8.76E-06    8.19E-06    7.30E-06    4.80E-06
                  4.18E-06  9.90E-06    5.21E-05    2.80E-06    1.26E-05    4.41E-06    4.41E-06    6.52E-06    6.44E-06    6.01E-06    5.32E-06    4.18E-06
                  4.33E-06  8.89E-06    4.37E-05    3.02E-06    1.32E-05    4.09E-06    3.94E-06    6.92E-06    6.82E-06    6.24E-06    5.35E-06    4.33E-06
                  3.18E-06  6.27E-06    4.98E-05    3.37E-06    1.09E-05    3.42E-06    3.43E-06    5.07E-06    4.98E-06    4.51E-06    3.84E-06    3.18E-06
                  4.25E-06  7.49E-06    3.72E-05    2.77E-06    1.34E-05    4.33E-06    4.23E-06    6.16E-06    6.09E-06    5.72E-06    5.11E-06    4.25E-06
                  4.14E-06  8.01E-06    3.82E-05    2.43E-06    1.57E-05    4.06E-06    4.03E-06    6.76E-06    6.67E-06    6.16E-06    5.33E-06    4.14E-06
                  4.79E-06  6.83E-06    4.76E-05    3.03E-06    1.57E-05    4.70E-06    4.65E-06    5.88E-06    5.82E-06    5.51E-06    5.07E-06    4.79E-06
                  4.16E-06  7.14E-06    5.33E-05    2.69E-06    1.32E-05    3.59E-06    3.43E-06    7.07E-06    6.95E-06    6.30E-06    5.26E-06    4.16E-06
                  3.12E-06  6.04E-06    3.96E-05    3.16E-06    8.78E-06    3.28E-06    3.20E-06    4.92E-06    4.84E-06    4.42E-06    3.79E-06    3.12E-06
                  3.68E-06  6.67E-06    4.15E-05    2.77E-06    1.01E-05    3.48E-06    3.34E-06    6.96E-06    6.83E-06    6.17E-06    5.10E-06    3.68E-06
                  5.53E-06  1.13E-05    5.70E-05    3.48E-06    1.47E-05    5.76E-06    5.61E-06    1.03E-05    1.01E-05    9.25E-06    7.86E-06    5.53E-06
                  5.11E-06  7.31E-06    5.11E-05    3.45E-06    1.40E-05    4.78E-06    4.76E-06    7.81E-06    7.71E-06    7.19E-06    6.36E-06    5.11E-06
                  5.64E-06  1.14E-05    4.97E-05    3.98E-06    1.66E-05    5.89E-06    5.66E-06    8.35E-06    8.25E-06    7.72E-06    6.85E-06    5.64E-06
                  3.27E-06  8.04E-06    4.06E-05    2.45E-06    1.29E-05    3.53E-06    3.55E-06    6.33E-06    6.23E-06    5.71E-06    4.87E-06    3.27E-06
                  3.56E-06  5.06E-06    5.19E-05    2.05E-06    1.49E-05    2.97E-06    2.88E-06    4.32E-06    4.26E-06    3.96E-06    3.53E-06    3.56E-06
                  4.81E-06  7.89E-06    4.01E-05    3.36E-06    1.67E-05    5.12E-06    5.00E-06    5.75E-06    5.68E-06    5.34E-06    4.90E-06    4.81E-06
                  3.51E-06  7.00E-06    3.81E-05    2.86E-06    1.15E-05    3.14E-06    3.05E-06    5.59E-06    5.50E-06    5.04E-06    4.34E-06    3.51E-06
                  4.09E-06  7.60E-06    4.27E-05    1.93E-06    1.63E-05    4.07E-06    4.02E-06    5.03E-06    4.98E-06    4.75E-06    4.41E-06    4.09E-06
                  3.31E-06  6.49E-06    7.91E-05    3.30E-06    1.70E-05    3.88E-06    4.01E-06    3.77E-06    3.75E-06    3.63E-06    3.46E-06    3.31E-06", header=F)
```

**CODE 1**

```
pvalue<-matrix(nrow=12, ncol=12)

for(i in 1:length(colnames(x))){
  for(j in 1:length(colnames(x))){
    pvalue[i,j]<-wilcox.test(x[,i], x[,j], paired=TRUE)$p.value 
    colnames(pvalue) <- colnames(x)
    rownames(pvalue)<- colnames(x)} }
```

**CODE2**

```
library('MASS')
pairwise.wilcox.test(t(x), g = seq(1,12))
```

Why I got this message in R? Is there a problem with the code I used or what?

Comment: Follow the suggestion in `There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)` and check the warning messages. They are self-explaining

Comment: The warning is `In wilcox.test.default(x[, i], x[, j], paired = TRUE) :
  cannot compute exact p-value with ties`

Comment: @Roland, I read that but I have no idea to solve.

Comment: @Bappa Das, what does this mean and how to solve this warning?

Comment: It tells you that no exact p-values can be computed if your data contains ties, which it does. Only a p-value based on the normal approximation is possible, see `help("wilcox.test")`.

Comment: If you prefer to avoid the warnings, use `pairwise.wilcox.test(t(x), g = seq(1,12), exact = FALSE)`.

Comment: @Roland, thanks, now it gives me the result without the warning message, but I do not understand the problem clearly. "ties=the same columns"? or what was the problem? Also, why pairwise.wilcox.test has different results from wilcox.test?

Comment: The test is called "Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney **Rank** Sum test". This means, data has to be ranked. If (in the paired test), the differences between the two samples are not unique, you have ties. There is no algorithm for calculating an exact p-value in that case.

Comment: "ties" means "same *values*", not "same columns".

Comment: The two approaches are not equivalent because in `pairwise.wilcox.test` (i) you didn't specify a paired test and (ii) it adjusts p-values for multiple testing, which your manual approach doesn't do.